# Understanding the meaning of "are you hustling me?"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

In the *X-files*, FBI agent Mulder approaches a group of downtrodden people living on the street. He loudly asks if anybody knows a recently murdered person. People ignore him, except one man. The man says he knows who the victim was and wants to show Mulder some helpful information that may help him figure out what happened. The man asks for money, and when given money by the agent, shows him a sketch of a strange creature. Mulder feels he's being fooled, and says:

> Are you hustling me?

I've looked up *hustle* and the main meaning is similar to *push*. Dictionaries give swindle as a synonym, which seems to fit the context here. I'm trying to fully grasp the question so I can use it in other situations. My interpretation of hustle here is:

> Are you trying to quickly get rid of me (push me away) by giving me short or false information?

If this interpretation is correct, then can I ask the same question to, say, my teacher who gives me a very short, incomplete answer to make me go away because he is busy?

Comment: As a side note, **hustle** is a slang term like "con" meaning to "cheat, swindle in a small way" so that using it would cast your subject, whatever it happens to be, in the light of petty crime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[hustle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hustle)** (v) : 2b. to sell something to or obtain something from (someone) by energetic and especially underhanded activity : SWINDLE

Your definition is close to correct, but this definition of the verb "hustle" always includes the suggestion of *cheating* someone in some way.  For example, if I sell you a watch that I swear is a genuine [Rolex](https://www.rolex.com/), but which I know is actually a forgery, that's a kind of *hustle*.   Or, if I pretend to fall down after being hit by your car, and try to get you to pay me money for my "injuries", that's another kind of *hustle*.

Or, as in the movie [*The Hustler*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054997/), I pretend to be mediocre at a game in order to trick you into thinking you can easily win money from me, then, once you make large bets, I beat you and take your money.  As you might expect, there is some risk with this scheme, as Paul Newman eventually gets his thumbs broken after *hustling* the wrong men.

Every city has its population of *hustlers*, and there are endless ways someone (or some group) can *hustle* their victims.  These kind of schemes are not restricted to any particular country or culture.  As previously mentioned, the plot of many movies involve some kind of *hustle* (*The Sting*, *Matchstick Men*, *Dirty Rotten Scoundrels*, *The Producers*, *The Brothers Bloom*, etc.) although in many of these it's not clear who is *hustling* whom.

However I would not use "hustle" on your teacher unless you really want to imply (playfully or otherwise) that he is trying to cheat you.  Instead you want to use "brush me off".

> Hey, that's not a complete answer and you know it.  Are you just trying to **brush me off**?

Some dialects might also say "give me the brush".  "Blow me off" is also common, but somewhat less polite.

Comment: `"hustle" always includes the suggestion of cheating someone in some way` Often, but not always. For example, I may intentionally play pool badly to get you to play for money, at which point I reveal my true skill and fairly take your money. While this entails lying (at least non-verbally, by making yourself look like an unskilled player), it's not technically _cheating_ in any way.

Comment: @Flater It may not technically be cheating, but I would consider it to be cheating morally. In that scenario I've committed to an agreement for an exchange of money based on my knowledge of your skill level which you've essentially lied about. It would be like me telling you I am a world-class artist and can paint an accurate portrait of you, then taking your money to do that and handing you back a stick figure - that's not what you signed up for.

Comment: @Flater: It is certainly *cheating* in the sense of misrepresenting your skill. Wouldn't you say that a golfer who competes in a "handicap" tournament is cheating if he misrepresents his level of skill?

Comment: @caesay: Your example is quite the opposite. You are claiming to deliver, but need payment up front, and then don't actually deliver what was explicitly agreed upon ("an accurate portrait"). This is reneging on the agreement. That is not the same as the pool game, where the skill of the players is never an explicit agreement. At no point did the agreement stipulate the exact skill level that the hustler is allowed to use - the only stipulation is that _the hustler_ plays the game and not e.g. his friend.

Comment: @caesay: Using your definition of cheating, literally every bluff in a game would be considered cheating.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: "Cheating" is breaking the rules. For example, using a table with magnets and metal pool balls is cheating. Playing the game well is not cheating, regardless of the skill you portrayed before. Immoral when done to win money from unsuspecting victims, I do agree. But it does not break any rule of the game nor the wager, and thus is not _cheating_.

Comment: @Flater: But the rules are being broken, even if they're only tacitly understood and not spelled out on the wall in big letters or fine print.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Implicit "rules" are not rules. That's an expectation, and while you can certainly not live up to it, doing so is not cheating.

Comment: @Flater:  So you say.  Tell that to the guy who's breaking your thumbs.

Comment: @Flater, while I understand your argument, I couldn't possibly agree with it.   After all, Paul Newman had his thumbs broken when they found out he was *hustling* them, which they wouldn't have done unless they felt it was some kind of *fraud*.

Answer (score 2):

**Hustling** (and **swindling**) involves more than fooling someone or lying to them. **Hustling** is lying to someone *in order to get them to give you money*.

In your example from the X-Files, the man convinced Mulder to give him money by promising to give Mulder useful information about the victim. The money is why Mulder wondering if the man was hustling him.

So, unless your teacher is trying to get money from you, even a short answer that is designed to get rid of you is not hustling you.

Comment: The conclusion in this answer is effectively saying "bears are a type of mammal. Therefore,if it's not a bear is therefore not a mammal". You gave one particular common example of a hustle which happens to involve money, but that doesn't means that every hustle must by definition revolve around money.